# Platform.io upload to Teensy 3.6 via SWD (J-LINK)

Tags: arduino, teensy, platformio, swd

I am using the excellent http://platformio.org/ together with Visual Studio Code to develop for Teensy 3.6 (an Arduino compatible board).

This works great. But I wanted to do better debugging via SWD (serial wire debug).
So I disconnected the Arduino-compatible USB-chip and connected via SWD and  JLINK instead. Similar to this: https://mcuoneclipse.com/2017/04/29/modifying-the-teensy-3-5-and-3-6-for-arm-swd-debugging/

I can flash firmware that I built via platformio using the "J-Link Lite" software just fine. Also I can run the J-Link GDB Server without a problem.
But I can't get the IDE integration to work.

My `platformio.ini` looks like this:

```
[env:teensy36]
platform = teensy
board = teensy36
framework = arduino
upload_protocol = jlink
debug_tool = jlink
```

Still the upload_protocol is ignored and when I invoke upload (`platformio.exe run --target upload`) via the IDE all I get is

```
Linking .pioenvs\teensy36\firmware.elf
Checking program size
text       data     bss     dec     hex filename
17348       172    2696   20216    4ef8 .pioenvs\teensy36\firmware.elf
Building .pioenvs\teensy36\firmware.hex
Uploading .pioenvs\teensy36\firmware.hex
Teensy Loader, Command Line, Version 2.1
Read ".pioenvs\teensy36\firmware.hex": 17520 bytes, 1.7% usage
Soft reboot is not implemented for Win32
Waiting for Teensy device...
(hint: press the reset button)
```

So it's still trying to upload via Arduino compatible USB connection instead of via SWD connection. How can I get platformio to change the upload method or upload_protocol?

Answer (score 2):

From [Project Configuration File platformio.ini](http://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/projectconf.html), it provides an example of how to configure Jlink GDB server:

```
[env:bluepill_f103c8]
...
; Debug options
debug_tool = custom
debug_server =
    JLinkGDBServer
    -singlerun
    -if
    SWD
    -select
    USB
    -port
    2331
    -device
    STM32F103C8
```

If JLinkGDBServer.exe is not included in PATH, then you need to specify the full file name of JLinkGDBServer.exe.

I have tried this, it works.

There is another example of using JlinkGDBServerCL.exe - [J-Link and ST Nucleo](http://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/plus/debugging.html#j-link-and-st-nucleo).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I independently discovered the custom configuration. But I encountered several bugs. Fortunately the platformio support is excellent. I spent many hours with the the platformio team over email and teamviewer to get this board going with SWD. When this is finally resolved I will post a separate answer, and I am positive the fixes will reach the platformio main branch.